# How to hide part of a form div with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got some code from this platform and implemented it to hide part of my form div element. However it works, but it looks like it hides and unhides when I run it in a browser. when I click on the button to hide it it hides and unhides rapidly how do I solve this problem?

The code about what I have tried is show as thus:

```css
.hide{

  display: none !important;
  visibility: hidden !important; 
}

.show{

display: block;
visibility:visible;

}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>

    </title>

    <script src="jquery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">

    <script>


        $(document).ready(function() {
          //console.log('hello');
       
          $("#btn").on("click", function(){
            $("#form1").addClass("hide");
          })

        });

        
         //document.getElementById("form1").style.visibility="hidden";
          //document.getElementById("form1").style.display="none";
          
      
        </script>
        


</head>
<body>
<form>

<div id= "form1" class="show">
<label>Name</label>

<input type="text"/>
</div>

<br> <br>

<div id="form2">
<label>Email</label>

<input type="text"/>

</div>


<button type="submit" id="btn">more</button>


</form>




</body>


</html>
```

Comment: I've converted your code to a working snippet - it appears to work perfectly.  Can you provide a snippet that *demonstrates* the problem?

Comment: @freedomn-m Your edit helpfully solved the problem - namely that the button was submitting the form it resided in, as buttons are wont to do. This would produce the perceived behavior that the form elements "hides and unhides". The solution would be to either hook the event to a non-button element, or to `return false;` from the click event in order to prevent form submission.

Comment: The code i posted is what i ran that seems not to perfect

Comment: Whoa works perfect now like you said@freedomn-m

Comment: Oh ok..@AndreasEriksson.. that way i can still have everything in a form element right?

Comment: @AndreasEriksson thanks for pointing that out - I changed it so that it wouldn't try to post on the snippet.  It was not intentional to "fix" the issue while attempting to reproduce it.

Comment: Change your button from `<button type="submit" id="btn">more</button>` to `<button type="button" id="btn">more</button>` otherwise it attempts to submit the form which reloads the page which un-hides your input.

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks .. it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button type should be `type="button"`
`<button type="button" id="btn">more</button>`

Answer (score 1):

there're a lot to change in this code but if you just want it to work you can put your button out of the form or replace your event listener to this:

```
$("#btn").on("click", function(e){
  $("#form1").addClass("hide");
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

it's happening because your button is submitting the form and refreshing the page